# How do you read a HTTP response using the python sockets module?

Tags: python, sockets, proxy

I am implementing a simple web-proxy using the python sockets module. After forwarding on the client's HTTP request to the server I use the following method to read the response:

```
def _read_response(self):
    response = ''
    while True:
        (readable, _, error) = select.select([self.server], [], [self.server], 3)
        if error:
            break
        if readable:
            data = self.server.recv(BUFSIZE)
            if not data: break
            response += data
    return response
```

The above code seems to work in most cases however it is **slow**. I narrowed this problem down to the line:

```
data = self.server.recv(BUFSIZE)
```

This call takes upwards of 20 seconds when there is no longer any data to receive (when data == '').

What is the correct way to read a http response and why does the call to recv() take so long?

Comment: Are you sure this is an HTTP proxy, or just a simple TCP proxy? It looks more like a TCP layer proxy. If HTTP proxy then it's not a simple as you think. You will have to handle headers intended for proxies, strip possible hop-by-hop headers, implement transfer-encoding, etc.

Comment: @Keith I'm simply trying to forward all client http requests on to the destination host. Then, after reading the request response, passing it back to the client (the web browser) to render the content.

Comment: How do you plan to handle the Host header value?

Comment: @Keith After reading the http request from the client I parse the Host: header and establish a connection to the server (self.server). I am now trying to correctly read the response from the server after passing on the client request.

Comment: OK, then you'll need to implement pipelining, the "chunked" method transfer-encoding, and also content-length for legacy servers (HTTP 1.0). These tell you how much data you have to read to avoid blocking. Otherwise it will wait until the server closes the connection, hence the long delay.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the **content-length** header before reading the body.
Then read only **content-length** bytes from the server.

You may want to set non-blocking mode of the socket by:

```
socket.setblocking(flag)
```

or set a timeout on the socket operation:

```
socket.settimeout(value)
```

Comment: There might not be a content length if chunked transfer-encoding is used.

Comment: I originally tried this method however when no Content-Length header was provided I encountered the same problem.

Comment: @Garee setting the non-blocking mode may help.